Are onboard hubs detected as USB root hubs or external devices?
I have connected an onboard hub to my microprocessor. The onboard hub is USB2514B and the microprocessor is a STM32MP1.
I can specify the the connection to the onboard hub by using OHCI (Open Host Controller Interface), but then I will get the error messages.
usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device

This means that OHCI (USB 1.1) cannot communicate with USB2514B, which requires USB 2.0 specification.
But if I connect my onboard hub by using EHCI (Enhanced Host Controller Interface), which is USB 2.0.
Then in Linux I will not get any errors about any device description. My lsusb looks like this:
>> lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Question:
Does this mean that this 1d6b:0002 is the USB2514B hub, or does it mean that it's the internal USB of the processor?
I'm looking for a way to confirm if I have connection to my USB2514B or if lsusb only shows my internal USB connection from the processor.
NOTE: This onboard USB hub does not require any external communication interfaces such as SMDbus, I2C or other. Only plain USB connection + linux device tree configuration.
&usbh_ehci{
    status = "okay";

    /* USER CODE BEGIN usbh_ehci */
    phys = <&usbphyc_port1>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    /* onboard HUB */
    hub@1 {
        compatible = "usb424,2514";
        reg = <1>;
        vdd-supply = <&v3v3>;
    };
    /* USER CODE END usbh_ehci */
};

&usbh_ohci{
    status = "disabled";
};

Useful sources:

https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/USB_overview
https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/USBH_device_tree_configuration


From the Linux Standard Error Codes, ETIME 62 /* Timer expired */. Your device isn't responding.

@waltinator only if I use OHCI, not for EHCI.

A hub is a hub, and gives no information on whether it's internal or external.
A host controller is a host controller, and not a hub. Don't conflate these two things!

Does this mean that this 1d6b:0002 is the USB2514B hub, or does it mean that it's the internal USB of the processor?


I'm looking for a way to confirm if I have connection to my USB2514B or if lsusb only shows my internal USB connection from the processor.

Well, you have one host controller, with a root hub, and one extra hub. Since you can't possibly see your hub without connecting it to the root hub, and you only see one entry, you already know your answer. Your hub IC isn't properly working or not properly connected to your root hub.

usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device


Well, here you see that something attached to the fourth port of your root hub (which is the first USB bus, device 1, so that's the 1-1 in there, and the .4 is for fourth port) isn't electrically reacting. This isn't a USB 1.1 vs USB 2.0 thing; the discovery would still work. So, you haven't connected the hub IC correctly, or it's not powered, or it's not starting up correctly, possibly due to being misconfigured or something. We can't tell you – this is a problem on a level completely separate from your operating system. It's a hardware problem.

I only get the error -62 when I'm using USB 1.1 (OHCI) to the USB2514B hub, which requires USB 2.0. When I'm using EHCI (USB 2.0), then I get no error -62.

do you still see your root USB hub in lsusb?

but either way, what you see, as already said, is definitely simply a USB device not properly working on the bus, no matter whether you're doing OHCI or EHCI! It's connected incorrectedly, not powered, or misconfigured.

I will do some research. When I lower RESET_N pin to 0V on my USB hub, then my processor can regonize the restart of the USB hub. I get the dmesg messages in the promt.

When I look at the microscope. The pin 25: HS_IND/CFG_SEL1 has a voltage divider of 100 kOhm. Which leaves to 0V when I measure the pin with DMM. But it can be 2.5V.

I think I found the issue now: USBDP_UP is about 3V when I measure it with my DMM. But USBDM_UP is about 0V. It seems not right there?

a) you really need to take this to the electrical engineering site; this has nothing to do with Linux/UNIX, and b) how is a DMM even remotely a sensible tool to debug a megabit pseudo-differential bus? It's not.

Thank you so much for your help. I will take this question to the electrical engineering site.
